# is it possible to have Interpolation within InnerHTML

Tags: angular, interpolation, innerhtml

I have a mat-table that loops through array of objects and renders data dynamically as such : `<span> {{column[element]}}</span`>. I want one of the cells to be a link but not the others.

I have tried using innerHTML like this:

```
<span innerHTML="(element === 'books') ? '<a>column[element]</a>' : column[element]"></span>
```

It is able to correctly recognize the dynamic data after the else statement (`:column[element]`) and it recognizes the A tags but it doesn't render the data between `<a></a>` as i want; but instead it reads it as a string. and prints out "`column[element]`" instead i want it to print out the books and make each book a link for that specific book.

I tried this approach with the same results:

```
<span innerHTML="(element === 'books') ? '<a>{{column[element]}}</a>' : column[element]"></span>
```

Comment: You can create `pipe` for that. And inside pipe you can use your conditions. and use this pipe with `[innerHTML]`.

Comment: It could be done with `[innerHTML]="condition ? '<a>' + var1 + '</a>' : var2"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope... You could use ng-switch. That's the angular way... Especially if you use AOT. Otherwise you would need JIT to be able to compile the template dynamically.

```
<span [ngSwitch]="element">
  <a *ngSwitchCase="'books'">{{column[element]}}</a>
  <ng-container *ngSwitchDefault>
    {{column[element]}}
  </ng-container>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked...to actually link it: 
<a target="_blank" href="blablabla/{{colum[element]}}"  *ngSwitchCase=" 'books' ">{{column[element]}}</a>

Comment: @JupiterFullMean You should use routerLink directive... Or aren't you using the angular router?